# check if string represents valid path in BASH

Tags: shell-script

I currently have a directory in a string, as such:
    `DESTDIR="/var/files/mydir/filedir/"`

Note that this directory does exist. I made sure of that.

I need to check if this directory already exists, or if I need to create it. I am currently doing this using:

```
if [ -d  $DESTDIR ]; then
    echo the directory exists!
else
    echo the directory does not exist!
fi
```

and, even though the directory does exist - I copy and pasted the name into the variable in my script - it always goes to the `else` statement. Not only that, but when I do `ls $DESTDIR` within the script I get a `no such file or directory` error. 
However, when I run `ls $DESTDIR` from the command line, I get the expected result.

I've tried replacing `$DESTDIR` with `"$DESTDIR"`, but I still don't get the expected result.

Comment: What's the output of `ls -ld "$DESTDIR"` and `printf %s "$DESTDIR" | od -t x1` ?

Comment: @Gilles first one: `ls: cannot access: No such file or directory`. Second one: `0000000`.

Comment: You haven't set the `DESTDIR` variable. Run that in your script, after setting the variable.

Comment: @Gilles the last value in the second one is `0d`, so there is a carriage return key being hit there. Ok. Thank you.

Comment: @Gilles I don't understand how a question with a completely different title can be a duplicate of another. the other question asks about Notepad++ and nano while I am asking a more general question that has nothing to do with the text editor used. Despite the solution being the same. I did my research and looked around stack looking for an answer to my question before asking, and did not find the question you marked and would not have looked at it even if I did find it, because it looks completely different.

Comment: That's the point of marking a question as duplicate: it's the same question (“I edited a shell script under Windows and it doesn't work”), with the same answers (no need to write new answers since the same answers work), that was formulated differently (so we keep both questions around).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just do `mkdir -p "$DESTDIR"` -- the `-p` option will suppress errors if it already exists.

Comment: Man, i totally misunderstood this question - i thought it was about the sstring - not the path. But you didn't.

Answer (score 0):

It looks from here like `$DESTDIR` (aka /var/files/mydir/file) is actually a /file/ instead of a /directory/. The `-d` test asks whether you have a /directory/. Check the output of `ls -ld $DESTDIR` to confirm. If `$DESTDIR` is indeed a file, then the `-d` test is doing the right thing -- just not what you expected.

Comment: that's terrible naming on my part. I'll change it for the example. But just a comment - if I run `ll /var/files/mydir/` from the command line, I get that the directory I am interested in is indeed a directory.

Comment: Is $DESTDIR actually set within the script? Or are you exporting it from your current shell?

Comment: I have the line `DESTDIR="/var/files/mydir/..."` shown above within my script. The directory is not _made_ within the script, though. And I am not exporting anything. All I did was pick a directory and copy/paste its path onto my script. Would that be the problem? How come?

Comment: Can you add a: `print '%s\n' "$DESTDIR"` before your `if [ -d ...` line just to confirm that DESTDIR is being set as you expect?

Comment: yup, if I do `echo ls $DESTDIR`, then from my console copy and paste this command, I get the expected result. Is there any chance this is a permissions issue?